# Jquery slider handle doesn't move

Tags: jquery, slider, handle

I'm upgrading our drupal 6 website to drupal 7 and with it comes a newer version of Jquery. I have a slidergallery with some boxshots that you can navigate through horizontally, and on the new site you can still scroll through the content but the handle doesn't move.

Any idea why the slider still works but the handle itself not anymore?

I tried the slider at [JqueryUi.com](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll) as well but with that one the slider doesn't even show up...

The initial version was based on [this slidergallery](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/) but that one can't be used anymore because of the Jquery update.

The css:

```
     /* slider specific CSS */
body.page-node-483 .sliderGallery {
     background: url(/sites/all/themes/fourpees2011/css/images/productbrowser-background3.png) no-repeat;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     padding: 10px;
     height: 200px;
     width: 960px;
 }

body.page-node-483 .sliderGallery ul {
     position: absolute;
     list-style: none;
     overflow: none;
     white-space: nowrap;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }

body.page-node-483 .sliderGallery ul li {
     display: inline;
     margin-right: 30px;
 }

body.page-node-483 .sliderGallery ul li.first {
     margin-left: 20px;
 }

body.page-node-483 .slider {
     width: 950px;
     height: 19px;
     margin-top: 160px;
     margin-left: 5px;
     padding: 1px;
     position: relative;
     background: url(/sites/all/themes/fourpees2011/css/images/productbrowser-scrollbar2.png) no-repeat;
 }

body.page-node-483 .handle {
     position: absolute;
     cursor: move;
     height: 19px;
     width: 187px;
     top: 0;
     background: url(/sites/all/themes/fourpees2011/css/images/productbrowser-scroller2.png) no-repeat;
     z-index: 100;
 }

body.page-node-483 .slider span {
     color: #bbb;
     font-size: 80%;
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 110;
     top: 3px;
 }
```

The script :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var container = $('div.sliderGallery');
        var ul = $('ul', container);

        var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();

        $('.slider', container).slider({
            min: 0,
            max: itemsWidth,
            handle: '.handle',
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1}, 500);
            },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="sliderGallery">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/products/atomyx/atomyx-portal"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/boxshot_Atomyx-Portal_LEFT_LR.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/axaio-software/madetoprint"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/MadeToPrint_0.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/axaio-software/madetocompare"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/MadeToCompare_0.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/axaio-software/madeforlayers"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/MadeForLayers.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/callas-software/pdftoolbox"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/pdfToolbox_0.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/callas-software/pdftoolbox-server"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/pdfToolboxServer_0.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/callas-software/pdfapilot"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/pdfaPilot_0.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/callas-software/pdfapilot-server"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/pdfaPilotServer_0.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/ctrlpublishing/ctrlchanges"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/CtrlChanges.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/ctrlpublishing/ctrllayers"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/CtrlLayers.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/ctrlpublishing/ctrlcrosstalkid"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/CtrlCrossTalkID.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/ctrlpublishing/ctrlcrosstalk"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/CtrlCrossTalk.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/elpical/claro-premedia"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/ClaroPremedia.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/elpical/claro-single"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/ClaroSingle.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/printfactory/printfactory"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/PrintFactory_0.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/printfactory/printfactory-go"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/PrintFactory_Go_Boxshot_0.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/proofmaster/proofmaster-plus"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/ProofMasterPlus.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/proofmaster/proofmaster-certify"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/ProofMasterCertify.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/proofmaster/proofmaster-media"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/ProofMasterMedia.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/remote-director/remote-director"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/Remote-director.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/remote-director/press-director"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/Press-director.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/twixl-media/twixl-publisher"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/Twixl-boxshot.png"></li></a>
            <li><a href="/products/twixl-media/twixl-publisher-enterprise-kiosk"<li><img src="/sites/default/files/products/boxshots/small/Twixl-Enterprise-Kiosk-boxshot.png"></li></a>
        </ul>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The whole is on JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vTr5c/2/

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar "slider handle doesn't move" issue when migrating from jquery-1.7.1.min.js to jquery-1.9.1.min.jss. On my side and after test it's —for sure— due to this file change. Some syntaxe within Jquery may have change from 1.7.1 to 1.9.1. I was not able to get your code/slider appear on JSfiddle. jsfiddle.net/vTr5c/2/